# How to edit text in textbox when text is highlighted? (Moved to textbox by tab)

Tags: c#, winforms

Clicked datagridview row's header to place row values from datatable to textboxes. So problem is that I can't edit textbox values when I move there by tab before I click highligted text off and see cursor in textbox.

Problems are only in those textboxes, where I set limitations (Like only numbers with one decimal point). I don't have that problem there where I read values from database to textboxes (where is also limitation but only numbers), and moved with tab to edit it. Photo from problem: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ekhn.jpg)

```
 private void productQuantity_txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != ',')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // sallii vain yhden desimaalipisteen
        if (e.KeyChar == ',' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(',') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {

            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

            if (textBox.Text.IndexOf(',') > -1 &&
                     textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.Text.IndexOf(',')).Length >= 2)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }

    }
```

I expect that when text is highlighted in textbox where I moved by tab and when I type new number to it, it replaces textbox's value by that. Now I can't do anything before I click that textbox to see cursor in it.

Comment: have you tried Masked textbox?

Comment: No, I haven't. I think regular textbox is better for this because I don't want that user need to type also decimals. User can type like 3000 or 1.5 and it saves it to datatable with 2 decimals.

Comment: if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {

            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;

            if (textBox.Text.IndexOf(',') > -1 &&
                     textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.Text.IndexOf(',')).Length >= 2)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }


Found what makes that problem.. That place where I allow user put only 2 digit after decimal point. If I remove this part then everything works fine.. So what makes it to block editing text in textbox when text is highlighted?